# How can I get rid of a button hover flicker that only happens with one particular button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, frontend

I have two buttons on this page. The top one 'get connected' is perfect as is and has no weird flicker. Yet, 'read more' towards the bottom has this weird flicker after the mouse moves away from the button.

https://dev.evolutionaryeducation.org/

I've never seen this before and everything I've tried has failed to work. I've reached out to support for hosting and they said 'this is just how browsers work'.

Comment: in your base.css file. the class `.button-stroke a.button:not(.action_button)` has a transition on it. Get rid of it or overwrite it with no transition which is recommended rather than altering the base.css file itself and it'll fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text in that button changes some of it's properties when you hover over the container button and those changes to the text happen immediately.

The flicker which you see is caused by the contents of the button (the text) not transitioning at the same speed as the main button does.

This css could be applied to your page (you can place this in the CSS tab of on the WordPress customizer page) to make the contents inside the button transition at the same speed as the surrounding button.

I tested this and the flicker disappears for me when it's applied.

```
.button.button_size_2.button_js span.button_label {
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: fixed! thanks a lot. I can use this for future reference now.

Comment: @AmarPatel No problem, happy to have been able to help :D If this answers your question please mark it as the correct answer so that it doesn't show up in the unanswered queue anymore. EDIT: just noticed it was marked as the correct answer, I just hadn't refreshed the page. Soon as I posted the comment it updated. Silly me :p